# asp.net 3.5 Treeview Empty after Postback

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have an asp.net page which has a web control. 
This web control displays a Treeview, TextBox and a button.

For the treeview i do on Page_Load:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    BindTreeView();
}
```

This is my TreeView definition:

```
   <asp:TreeView ID="TvwData" runat="server" 
        BackColor="White" ShowCheckBoxes="Leaf" Width="99%" 
        ExpandDepth="3"  AutoGenerateDataBindings="false" 
        onselectednodechanged="TvwData_SelectedNodeChanged" 
        EnableViewState="true"
       >
```

The TreeView is shown correctly.

However, when I click the submit button, the following happens:

1. Page reloads, textbox still displays my text which is OK.
2. My Treeview doesn't display any data at all.
3. When debugging, TvwData.CheckedNodes doesn't contain any data while I'm sure there are treeview items checked.

I really tried my best to found a solution on major ASP.NET forums, but I'm clueless at this moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there are a certain code for the submit button? If so, please post it as well.

Comment: After, check in page directives if is set EnableViewState="true"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        BindTreeView();        
    }
```

Furthermore, remove BindTreeView(); from Page_Load.

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old post but I just ran across it. It's just that I had the same problem, and your answer seems to solve it totally. Could you pls explain why the binding should be done in OnInit and doesn't work in Page_Load? Thanks.